# Style of cursor is not changing

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

I have a code to put a wait cursor on all the images when a image is clicked.

```
function disableButton()
{
 idStopSelBtn.style.cursor='wait';
 idStartSelBtn.style.cursor='wait';
 idBounceRunningBtn.style.cursor='wait';
 idStopAllBtn.style.cursor='wait';
 idStartAllBtn.style.cursor='wait';
 idBounceSelBtn.style.cursor='wait'
}
```

When the function called by clicking of button gets I designed another function to take away wait cursor and put default cursor.

```
function enableButton(strType)
{
idStopSelBtn.style.cursor='default';
idStartSelBtn.style.cursor='default';
idBounceRunningBtn.style.cursor='default';
idStopAllBtn.style.cursor='default';
idStartAllBtn.style.cursor='default';
idBounceSelBtn.style.cursor='default';
alert('done');  
}
```

The wait sign is still not going after calling this function. I just added alert to check if the function is firing or not and it's firing, still cursor sign is not changing.

Comment: How are you calling this second function? Creating a jsfiddle would help better us understand the issue.

Answer (score 0):

try setting it to auto instead of default:

```
function enableButton(strType) {
    idStopSelBtn.style.cursor='auto';
    idStartSelBtn.style.cursor='auto';
    idBounceRunningBtn.style.cursor='auto';
    idStopAllBtn.style.cursor='auto';
    idStartAllBtn.style.cursor='auto';
    idBounceSelBtn.style.cursor='auto';
    alert('done');  
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This is what you need.

```
idStopSelBtn.Attributes.Add( "onclick", "document.body.style.cursor = 'wait';" );
```

Please correct me if I am wrong. I am not a .net developer and I guess this is .net code and our team is doing like this...

I hope it may help...

EDIT it as you want. Instead of putting direct css code there itself call a js function and proceed with default and wait cursor manipulation there.